# unrecognizable characters utf8

Tags: php, mysql, windows, ubuntu

I just finished to create a web, but when i upload this web to the server, the web codification doesn’t take the accents, the accents like “ ´ ” or  “ ` “, over the inserted data on the database.

I have been working on the programation on a eclipse running Windows, but the web server it’s based on Ubuntu.

The configuration of the server it’s:

Apache:
I have modified the archive `/etc/apache2/conf.d/charset`

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Php5

```
Archive modified "/etc/php.ini"

default_charset = "utf-8"
```

mysql

```
Archive modified “/etc/mysql/my.cnf”
```

[client]

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

[mysql]

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

[mysqld]

```
init_coonect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_coonect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

And when I check the variables of mysql with the comand show variables like “%character%”; it returns me all utf8.

html5:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

create and save the archives in `utf8`
I save the archives in utf8

When i check the answer of http header, this answer me content-type text/html;

```
charset=utf8
```

Mysql connections

```
mysql_set_charset(“utf8”,$conectar_BD);
```

As you can see, all it’s correct, what i’m doing wrong??
Like i said before, there are two rare things.

1 If i insert the name of user with accent “´”, when I print by screen the variable that contains the name from the variable session[‘name’] it works correct, but when i print from the object it show’s a pity characters

2 How i commented before, if I do the consultation of the db on my local computer it show a correct caracters, but if i do the same consultation from the server no.